# What happens when NULL pointers are returned from "foreign functions" using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

When wrapping C functions with ctypes what happens when a method returns a NULL pointer to a struct mapped to a python class derived from ctypes.Structure?  Also what happens when valid pointers passed to a method are set to NULL values?  The following test will help us find out:

```
//python_ctypes_test.c
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test_struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} typedef test_struct;

test_struct* get_test_struct(const int valid) {
    test_struct* newStruct = 0;
    if (valid > 0) {
        newStruct = malloc(sizeof *newStruct);
        newStruct->a = 1;
        newStruct->b = 2;
        newStruct->c = 3;
        newStruct->d = 4;
    }
    return newStruct;
}

void get_two_floats(const int valid, float* float1, float* float2) {
    if (valid > 0) {
        *float1 = 1.1f;
        *float2 = 2.2f;
    } else {
        float1 = 0;
        float2 = 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
#python_ctypes_test.py
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

dll = ctypes.CDLL('libpython_ctypes_test.so')

class _test_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", ctypes.c_int),
                ("b", ctypes.c_int),
                ("c", ctypes.c_int),
                ("d", ctypes.c_int)]

    def wrap(self, something):
        self.a,self.b,self.c,self.d = something

    def unwrap(self):
        part1 = self.a,self.b
        part2 = self.c,self.d
        return part1, part2

dll.get_test_struct.restype = ctypes.POINTER(_test_struct)
dll.get_test_struct.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
def py_get_test_struct(valid):
    return dll.get_test_struct(valid).contents.unwrap()

def py_get_test_struct_safe(valid):
    testStructPtr = dll.get_test_struct(valid)
    if testStructPtr: 
        return testStructPtr.contents.unwrap()
    else:
        return None

dll.get_two_floats.restype = None
dll.get_two_floats.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, 
        ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)]
def py_get_two_floats(valid):
    float1_value = ctypes.c_float(0)
    float1 = ctypes.pointer(float1_value)
    float2_value = ctypes.c_float(0)
    float2 = ctypes.pointer(float2_value)

    dll.get_two_floats(valid, float1, float2)

    return float1_value.value, float2_value.value

print py_get_two_floats(True)
print py_get_two_floats(False)
print py_get_test_struct_safe(True)
print py_get_test_struct_safe(False)
print py_get_test_struct(True)
print py_get_test_struct(False)
```

Comment: Download source code: https://github.com/trukvl/python_ctypes_test

Comment: Do you think something is missing from the [ctypes pointers tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#pointers)? It discusses their boolean value and demonstrates the `ValueError`.

Comment: I suppose I would like to see a section discussing how ctypes handles NULL pointers returned from C functions and pointers passed by reference that are changed to NULL pointers by the C function.  It is not clear to me the these points are addressed directly.

Comment: It does discuss `NULL` pointers; it doesn't matter how they're created. The C function returns an integer value in a register (e.g. `rax` in x64), and ctypes creates a pointer instance from that value, which could be 0. For the 2nd question, you aren't passing pointers by reference. You're passing them by value.

Comment: Instead of creating a pointer instance, generally you'd just use `float1 = ctypes.c_float()` and pass a reference as `ctypes.byref(float1)`. That's passing a reference to the float value, but the address itself is passed by value, either on the stack or in a register (e.g. register `rcx` in x64).

Comment: Agreed, that makes the most sense.  The API I was testing instantiated floats the way this example does.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the developer need not be concerned about the address of a pointer, that has been passed to a function, changing.

```
print py_get_two_floats(True)
  (1.100000023841858, 2.200000047683716)

print py_get_two_floats(False)
  (0.0, 0.0)
```

In the second case the values remain unchanged from their initialized state.  This is generally true.  Had `float1_value` and `float2_value` been initialized to 10 and 20.  Those values would have been remained unchanged as well.

As @eryksun points out:

> float1 and float2 are local variables that contain the address of the
> two floats. You can set the value to 0, or any other address, but
> that's just changing a local variable. That's not the same as
> dereferencing the pointer (e.g. *float1) to access the floating point
> value at the address.

In the case of return values things are handled differently.  The object returned evaluates to true (non-null) or false (null).

```
print py_get_test_struct_safe(True)
  ((1, 2), (3, 4))

print py_get_test_struct_safe(False)
  None
```

Attempting to access a NULL pointer results in a ValueError exception.

```
print py_get_test_struct(True)
  ((1, 2), (3, 4))

print py_get_test_struct(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_ctypes.py", line 52, in <module>
    print py_get_test_struct(False)
  File "python_ctypes.py", line 24, in py_get_test_struct
    return dll.get_test_struct(valid).contents.unwrap()
ValueError: NULL pointer access
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a lesson in basic C programming? (1) `float1` is a local variable in `get_two_floats`, so of course setting it to 0 has no effect in the context of the caller. (2) As to accessing a `NULL` pointer, you could simply use `ctypes.POINTER(_test_struct)().contents` to demonstrate the `ValueError`.

Comment: I shared this example because I was debugging code that uses pyGLFW (a wrapper around the GLFW C library). I had questions about what the python would return if the C code returned null in the two cases I demonstrated. Since I couldn't find a good example that answered this question, I decided to post it.

Comment: `float1` and `float2` are local variables that contain the address of the two floats. You can set the value to 0, or any other address, but that's just changing a local variable. That's not the same as dereferencing the pointer (e.g. `*float1`) to access the floating point value at the address.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake now.  You are correct, ```float1``` and ```float2``` will never be NULL after the C call.  I misread the API I was testing.  I will revise my answer to reflect this.